# GUI Design with Small File Size

Tags: file, user-interface, embedded

I am an embedded software enginner who has to design a **GUI with a low file size**.

I need to design an application that will stay in a NAND flash. Memory limit is about **750 Kb** and it will be super basic design. Application will have some combo boxes, user will select some and will click apply. And the program will write stuff to a file in the nand flash. This app should work for **Windows**.

We have a similar app works great in Windown but it is designed with a huge framework. I need an GUI Design IDE/SDK/FrameWork/Platform advice that will let me create simple interface with simle features and with a **low file size** (Lower than 1 Mb).

Comment: You may consider using FATFS. There are many porting libraries for this file system in various MCU.

Comment: And your question is what? If you are looking for a recommendation, this is off-topic, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LVGL](https://lvgl.io). It's open source, easy to port, and designed for embedded systems (but runs on Windows too) so has a small memory footprint.